# Getting count of TLB misses that resulted in memory access in x86-64

Tags: x86-64, cpu-architecture, intel, tlb, intel-pmu

I want to know the number of TLB misses that resulted in memory (DRAM) access. In "Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2104" system, I can see perf counters like "**dtlb_load_misses.miss_causes_a_walk**" and "**dtlb_store_misses.miss_causes_a_walk**" which gives count of page table walks (even though these counts are higher than what I expected), now is there a direct or indirect way to correlate these counts with some other perf event to approximate address translation memory accesses?

I was thinking of correlating with LLC misses as it corresponds to memory accesses, but I could not finalize a strategy to filter out translation misses from LLC misses.

Comment: On my Skylake-client CPU, I don't see (in Linux `perf list`) any event that counts whether the page-walker's accesses hit in L1, L2, L3, or not at all.  In offcore requests, that probably falls under `offcore_requests.demand_data_rd`; I wonder if iTLB misses count as code reads?  I think that's what you're wanting to count.  It *might* be possible somehow, but I'm not optimistic.  Indirect means are unlikely, page-walker accesses that miss in L3 are probably very rare compared to other demand loads, so even if there was something, you'd be subtracting two big noisy numbers, getting only noise.

Comment: (My other guess is if you're wanting to count loads caused a page-walk and then also missed in L3 cache once the physical address was available.  I don't think there's a counter for that either.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for your comment. I am interested in studying the overhead of TLB misses due to memory accesses for translating address (excluding translations hitting in cache as cache access are faster). One another approach I was considering was to depend on some architecture simulators to get this count.

Comment: Yeah that could work.  I expect the overhead is pretty low since page walks can hit in cache, so maybe another effect you could look for is L1d evictions caused by page walks.  Or if simulating, you can play "what if" and simulate page walks as being as fast as if they'd hit in L1d, but not actually evict any lines from any levels of cache.  And look at the difference in cache hit rates with / without the extra accesses to PTEs and PDEs.  (The page walkers can internally cache some upper levels of tables, and/or the bytes surrounding the last PTE it accessed, making sequential access cheaper)